# Dynamic attribute key selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic-programming, query-selector

I'm basically trying to build a function that searches all nodes on the DOM to check for data attributes, then swap them out with whatever is stored with the "data-intl-" attribute. For example, if someone had `data-intl-attr`, whatever `attr` is on, that node would get replaced by what's in `data-intl-attr`.

The code works; I just want to know if I could have approached it differently.

```
var all = $('*');

$.map(all,function(el) {

    filter($(el).data(), function(clean){
      var originalAttrVal = $(el).attr(clean);
      var intlAttr = $(el).attr("data-intl-" + clean);

      $(el).attr(clean, intlAttr);

    });


});


function filter(foo, cb){
        var capture;
    for(var i in foo) {
      if (foo.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        i = i.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1-$2').toLowerCase();
        i = i.replace(/intl-/g, '');
        capture= i;
     }      
     cb(capture);
  }

}
```

Input HTML:

```
<a href="a-link.html" data-intl-href="newval.html">test href</a>
<img src="https://test.com/logo.png" data-intl-src="newval.png">
```

Output HTML:

```
<a href="newval.html" data-intl-href="newval.html">test href</a>
<img src="newval.png" data-intl-src="newval.png">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. ### Naming Conventions

   The variable `all` doesn't tell what it contains. `allElements` does reflect what it contains.

   `clean`, `i`, `foo`, `capture` - huh?

   `filter`, the name of the function has nothing to do with filtering. It is iterating over some data and calling provided callback for each property.
2. ### Global Variables

   `all` is global variable. Global variables is bad practice. Please see [Why are global variables considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525582/why-are-global-variables-considered-bad-practice) and [I've Heard Global Variables Are Bad, What Alternative Solution Should I Use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613310/ive-heard-global-variables-are-bad-what-alternative-solution-should-i-use).
3. ### Using Proper Methods

   `map` is used to update each element in collection. Here, `map` is used just to iterate over the elements. You can use `each`, `for`, `forEach`, etc. in such case.
4. ### Diving into DOM

   In `filter` callback, you're *diving* into DOM three times to get the same element. The element can be cached and reused.
5. ### Method Chaining

   `replace()` in `filter()` can be chained.
6. ### Unnecessary code

   `foo.hasOwnProperty(i)` is not required as `.data()` only returns `data-*` properties in an object.
   `.toLowerCase()` can be safely removed and `i` flag on the next `replace` regex can be used.

   Also, HTML is case insensitive. No transformation is needed when changing attribute.

---

That is too much code for such a small functionality. I've rewritten the code. See the explanation in the code comments.

```js
// Select all elements in DOM
// and iterate over them
$('*').each(function() {
  // Cache the element reference
  // $(this) refers to the current element in the collection
  var $this = $(this);

  // Get the key-value of all `data-*` attributes
  // on current element
  var data = $this.data();

  // Get all the keys of data-attributes
  var keys = Object.keys(data);

  // Check if this element have data-* attribute on it
  if (keys.length) {

    // Iterate over each data attribute
    keys.forEach(function(key) {

      // Check if attribute starts with `intl` followed by Uppercase character
      if (/^intl[A-Z]/.test(key)) {
        // Get the attribute name
        // As the attribute name is camelCase, last word is the attribute name
        var attribute = key.match(/[A-Z][a-z]*$/)[0];

        // Update the attribute in DOM
        $this.attr(attribute, data[key]);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="a-link.html" data-intl-href="newval.html" data-link="Like this???">test href</a>
<img src="https://test.com/logo.png" data-intl-src="newval.png" data-intl-alt="Can have multiple attributes">
```

Comment: I wanted to check for data-intl in case there was another data tag present on that node. Your code fails if say for example there's a "data-link" attribute on the node

Comment: I was trying to avoid using an each loop, thanks i just need to update the regex

Comment: @Seeker I've added condition to check if the attribute starts with `intl`.